# Ubuntu app stores and 32 and 64 bits apps

Tags: 64-bit, application-development, 32-bit, multiarch

Is there any tutorial to submit applications in multiple architectures ?

- if only one architecture is submitted, I guess 64 bits is recommended today ? (do we have stats on how many users use 32 vs 64 bits ?)
- do we need to create 2 apps with 2 different package and version names ?
- do we have to take into consideration multiarch ?

Other tips appreciated :)

Comment: I submitted 32 bit package and source code, They built 64 bit package for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are submitting free open source applications to the [Application Review Board](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard/) they require a Launchpad PPA, if you are submitting to the [commercial MyApps developer program](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/) a tar/zip file with both 32 and 64-bit versions is best.